# Form dataset update

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using devexpress component "XtraCharts" to be able to prepare a graphical report. I designed a dataset and attached it to the chart. The values from the database appear in the report. There is no problem up to here.

But in my application I read data from a sensor so values come to db consecutively and I need to refresh this dataset every 5 seconds.

How can I do this in a C# winforms application?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [timer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398865.aspx) - here is an [example tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp11302005054911AM/WorkingwithTimerControlinCSharp.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Timer` to your form, set its interval to 5000ms and on timer `Tick` event update your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class. You can set the interval you wish the timer to "Tick" at and when the timer ticks update your chart.

Comment: it works now but it grafic update does not conform to interval I set.I mean I set intervel 5000 but it updates 10000ms and sometimes it stucks.Is there any solution to be able to edit this problem..Thanx

Comment: I guess this could be down to a number of things. How long does it take to retrieve the data from the database? If this takes 5 seconds then it's going to appear like the refresh is only happening every 10 seconds.